# Jaxb 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I keep getting this error and my application won't start, should I have this in a try {   block ?

Unmarshal

```
File file = new File("xmlFiles/ipAdresses.xml");

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(IpAdressListXmlHandler.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            IpAdressListXmlHandler xmlList = (IpAdressListXmlHandler) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(xmlList);
```

no file, I deleted it

the class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JAXBHandler {

    private String serverid;
    private String clientFileDir;
    private String serverFileDirectory;
    private int port;



    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }


    public void setClientFileDir(String dir) {
        this.clientFileDir = dir;
    }




    public void setServerFileDirectory(String serverDir) {
        this.serverFileDirectory = serverDir;
    }


    public void setServerId(String serverId) {
        this.serverid = serverId;
    }


    @XmlElement
    public String getServerid() {
        return serverid;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getClientFileDir() {
        return clientFileDir;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getServerFileDirectory() {
        return serverFileDirectory;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
```

I hope this is something simple, been fondling with this all night(seriously)

Comment: Schow the stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need write code inside of try{} block, And make sure Your @XmlRootElement is also present to unmarshall , It is indicate that This is base object class for, all other sub classes.

```
 File file = new File("xmlFiles/ipAdresses.xml");
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(IpAdressListXmlHandler.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        IpAdressListXmlHandler xmlList = (IpAdressListXmlHandler) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(xmlList);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IpAdressListXmlHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```